# How to remove padding/minHeight/minWidth from a button?

Tags: android, button, material-design

I've got this code:

**MyActivity**

```
Button button = new Button(MyActivity.this);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_button);
button.setText(word);
button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
button.setMinimumHeight(0);
button.setMinimumWidth(0);
button.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.abc_primary_text_material_dark));

view.addView(button);

button.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this, R.anim.abc_fade_in));
```

**my_button.xml**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">


    <solid android:color="@color/primaryColor" />

    <corners android:radius="12dp" />

    <padding
        android:left="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:top="3dp" />

</shape>
```

This button is dynamically added to a layout. The problem is that the button will have a default minHeight/minWidth even if I set those to 0. I noticed that when the button has `a` as text, the padding is there, but if the word is long enough the padding left/right shrinks to the value I set in the xml.

Comment: why not just skip the set to zero statements and just define a second xml with the layout you want and them swap them as needed.